# English equivalent of Russian "по кд" meaning "used repeatedly and as soon as possible"

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, russian

There's a Russian gaming phrase "по кд" which means "fired/activated/used repeatedly and as soon as possible after the cooldown time".
The example of it being used in World of Tanks - "Зашёл к нему в спину и начал разваливать по кд", which roughly translates as "Flanked him and started damaging with all the DPS available".

The phrase mainly used in gaming, but it may be used in other domains, for example, programming - "Начал слать запросы по кд", which translates as "Started sending requests with a minimum possible downtime (be it receiver or sender restrictions, depends on the context)."

Is there an English equivalent for this Russian phrase?

I tried to use the literal slang translation, **on/at cooldown**, but it rather means "the thing is not ready (it is on cooldown)".
Another option, **fire at will**, roughly means "fire when ready", but it barely concerns the weapon itself.

So, is there an English phrase or idiom that means "по кд"?

Comment: Note to potential answerers: the original phrase is extremely niche and obscure. So if the translation you are about to suggest can be understood by your nan, or indeed by any speaker of English at all, it is not a good translation and you must carry on looking for a better one.

Comment: What does the abbreviation stand for? Presumably KD is not a word in Russian.

Comment: There's a phrase "rode hard and put up wet," referring to a horse that was ridden extensively and not given a proper cooldown. While this gets the sense of used up and put away, it does not get the repeated sense of "ridden as soon as the horse was no longer sweaty (and got some hay / oats and water)."

Comment: @Mitch I’m guessing probably _кулдаун_ (or some similar transliteration of _cooldown_). I don’t really understand what the meaning is, though. Ramid, what does this describe? In which state? If something is recharging, that sounds like a phone or camera or some other type of battery – but recharging your phone is not the same as it being on cooldown (which I would interpret as just lying around, unused), and it doesn’t seem related to “activated/used repeatedly”. _Fire at will/when ready_ sounds like it’s to do with weapons, which doesn’t fit the rest at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I apologize for not clarifying it from the start. This is mostly a gaming term, where кд_is literally an abbreviated _cooldown_. The phrase по кд is used when the ability is used repeatedly as soon as the cooldown is gone. However, this term can be used outside of gaming situations too. I'll add the info to the question.

Comment: You mentioned "fire at will", but here is also [_fire for effect_](https://us.cnn.com/videos/politics/2019/10/24/colorado-border-wall-moos-pkg-ebof-vpx.cnn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've met the following case.

In the chapter 239 of "He who fights with monsters", the author uses **on cooldown** as the equivalent of what I meant (по кд).

> Both Belinda and Clive had been using their rune trap powers on cooldown.

EDIT: I've also found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/wow/comments/6t2e63/n00b_question_cast_on_cooldown_meaning/) reddit question featuring the same issue. In the thread, it was mentioned that the guides and manuals also used `on cooldown` with the same meaning that I meant, that is `using the ability right after it comes off cooldown`. I think that's enough of a basis to consider this question being answered fully.

Comment: That's really not an answer to this question, even if it is your own question. If a power is *on cooldown* it can't, by definition, be used. Unless "Belinda and Clive" had found an exploit, i.e., they'd found a way to cheat, they couldn't have been doing what the author says. So unless "по кд" means cheating, this answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Robusto, with this example being present. I started to look more at the previous answer - spam. I understood that it has the negative emotional sense that doesn't correlate with по кд. What is more, this question is half a year old. I guess we've figured out that there's no stable phrase in English to relay по кд. More than that, the original phrase doesn't make sense in Russian too if we were to use the standard meanings. Слать запросы по кд would mean something like "send requests by using cooldown".

Answer (score 3):

[From what I understand](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&u=https://teenslang.su/id/26228&prev=search), your expression (по кд) is a gaming term, so the word you are looking for is almost certainly “[**spam**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(gaming))”:

> **Spamming**, in the context of video games, refers to the repeated use of the same item or action. For example, "grenade spamming" is the act of a player throwing many grenades in succession into an area. In fighting games, one form of spamming would be to execute the same offensive maneuver or combo so many times in succession that one's opponent does not receive a chance to escape the series of blows.

Usually this is said of actions that have a short cool down (see also [*button mashing*](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Button_mashing)), but it is also used for moves in [turn based games](https://screenrant.com/pokemon-attacks-powerful-banned/), like Pokémon:

> [S]mart players will have planned ahead and will know how to avoid overusing the move [Protect]… which, ironically, will allow them to spam it against other players who might not be able to catch a break in between bouts of unbreakable Protect and swift attacks.

*[Spam](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Spam)* is used as both a verb and a noun (and *spamming* is also a noun/gerund):

> While the game [Super Smash Bros.] discourages spamming with stale-move negation, the point of spam is to throw out many attacks to the point where the reduced damage can be made up simply by using the move twice as much

Additionally, *spam* is used in programming to describe a system that produces output as fast as it can, in particular when it does it enough that it puts strain on (or even takes down) a system that is receiving its output:

> [How to Limit web requests per second to avoid spamming and denial of service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32561280/6083675)

Answer (score 0):

The closest counterpart in English seems to be "a spree". "Kill spree", "death spree", etc. The slang flavor is missing, of course, but in Russian the phrase is used outside of gaming a lot nowadays - especially by younger people - to mean "repeatedly", "easily", "quickly".